# Returning the data from a deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class that uses Google's places service. A user can enter an address and Google will return information about it.

Later on I wish to find out lat and lng coordinates on this place, so I have this method which utalizes Google's places service to get the coords.

I return a deferred as this may take some time.

```
p.getLatLong = function() {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

        this.placesService.getDetails({
            reference: this.pacReference
        }, function(details, status){
            if(details){
                dfd.resolve({'lat' : details.geometry.location.lat(), 'lng' : details.geometry.location.lng()});
            }
            else{
                dfd.reject();
            }
        })
    }

    return dfd;
};
```

I want to be able to access the above method and just return the coords or null (if the dfd is rejected) but the method returns a deferred.

How can I just return the result of the dfd rather than the dfd itself?

I do not wish to have to call:

```
this.geo.getLatLng().done(function(data){console.log(data})
```

But something like this:

```
console.log(this.geo.getLatLng());
```

Answer (score 0):

I get your point, though promises exist for a reason, the reason here being the asynchronous nature of asking for data.

There is a way, I used to think it was good before I understood the goal of promises. You could return the reference of the 'to be populated' data, but then, when will you be able to use it? Are you planning on polling the state of an object...? I hope not, seriously stick to promises you will avoid a lot of problems for small profit of a bunch of keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

Deferred objects are meant to allow the thread to continue while long running operations proceed in the background. They serve a specific purpose, and shouldn't work the way you describe by design.

Remember that JavaScript is single-threaded. That means that if you pause the thread waiting for a long operation to complete, the entire page/UI will be frozen as well.

---

That warning stated, you could potentially accomplish what you want by wrapping all this into your own closure with a loop that checks to see if the process completes.

**Please note this is dangerous, will freeze the page, and should be avoided. It is here for academic reasons only.**

```
var getGetLatLng = (function () {
    var running = false;

    return function () {
        var latlng;

        //While we haven't instructed the loop to break.
        while (!breakLoop) {
            //If we haven't instructed the API call to execute in this iteration of the loop.
            if (!running) {
                //On next iteration, tell it we are already running, to prevent multiple requests being fired.
                running = true;

                //Your logic here for getLatLng
                this.geo.getLatLng()
                    //When it completes successfully, set latlng
                    .done(function (data) {
                        latlng = data;
                    })
                    //always break the loop when HTTP completes.
                    .always(function () {
                        breakLoop = true;
                    });
            }
        }

        //Return latlng - it could be undefined if there was an error.
        return latlng;
    };
})();
```

You could wrap this same structure around your original `p.getLatLng` function body too. Again, I don't recommend it.